# How to run .js files in webview from android below 5.0?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-jsinterface

> I have some .js file with me. I load that html file from assets folder.`

```
WebView browser=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); 
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/network.html");`
```

> Its working for android 5.0 onwards but the animations are displaying slowly. And for android 4.0 the js files are not loading. Please anyone help me.

Comment: Are your JS files in the assets folder too ? How are you referencing them from the HTML or otherwise loading them ?

Comment: yes js files are in assets folder .

Comment: How are you referencing them from your HTML ? Please add the relevant part of your HTML to the question.

Comment: <html>
<body>
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="network-anim.js"></script>
</body>  its working fine for android 5.0 and above ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
  mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
mWebView.setFocusable(true);
mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    //Handle javascript alerts:
    @Override
public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result)  
{
  Log.d("alert", message);
  Toast.makeText(context, message, 3000).show();
  result.confirm();
  return true;
};
```